# How is a NSPopUpButton filled with data when using Core Data and Bindings?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I'm trying to figure out how a `NSPopUpButton` is filled with data when using core data and cocoa bindings. The reason is that I subclassed `NSPopUpButton` and I would like to manipulate the insertion of the menu items by adding an image to them.

I subclassed 
`- (void)addItemWithTitle:(NSString *)title`,
`- (void)addItemsWithTitles:(NSArray *)itemTitles` and 
`- (void)insertItemWithTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index`
just to see which method is called but none of them is on application start.

Does anybody know what's the correct method . The class reference doc isn't very helpful here (or I didn't get it how to use it) as there are no other methods listed which affect the item insertion.

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

This is how you fill your NSPopUpButton with data from CoreData:

Let's say you have the CoreData entity "Person" with the NSString property "name"

First create an NSArrayController in InterfaceBuilder and set it's mode to "Entity Name", enter the name "Person" and check "Prepares Content".

Now put a new NSPopUpBotton in your Interface and bind it's "Content Values" to the ArrayController. The Controller Key should be "arrangedObjects" and the Model Key Path "name".

(Now you just have to add some data)

A NSPopUpButton contains NSMenuItems. NSMenuItems can have an image. So you don't have to subclass it.

You could also create an Array with NSMenuItems, which have images and bind the Array to "Content" of your NSPopUpButton.

Comment: Hello Daniel! Thanks, but it's not what I'm looking for. I understand bindings and core data so far that I'm able to bind the controls. What I want is to know **which** method of `NSPopUpButton` is called when it is filled with data by core data / bindings so I can change the implementation to my needs.

Comment: Hello Daniel again. To the second part of your post. I have a core data entity with a name and a bitmap in it. What works is, that the names are bound to the `NSPopUpButton`- What I want to achieve is, that the bitmaps and the names are displayed. I didn't find a way to get it solely with the Interface Builder. The plan is, to leave the binding of the name in the entity as it is and to subclass the `NSPopUpButton` so that the images are added programatically when the control is fed with data. I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question but I do have the answer now after manually implementing the binding of `NSPopUpButton` with `NSTreeController`.

You can checkout my [NSTreePopUpButton](https://github.com/brutella/NSTreePopUpButton) project on Github to see how I have done it and I'm pretty sure that's how the `NSPopUpButton` does it as well.

As far as I can tell the `NSPopUpButton` overwrites

```
func bind(binding: String, toObject observable: AnyObject, withKeyPath keyPath: String, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?)
```

If `binding` is `NSContentBinding`, the class adds itself as an observer to the object and key path like.

```
observable.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: keyPath, options:..., context:...)
```

When the value at the key path changes the method

```
func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)
```

is called on `NSPopUpButton`. The implementation of this method either updates or creates a complete new `NSMenu` instance and assigns it to the [menu](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPopUpButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSPopUpButton/menu) property.